# how can we find distance duration(time) with google geocode api?

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, google-geocoder

How can we find distance duration(time) & distance between any of the world's two cities with google geocode api?

If I want to find the distance duration(driving time) between 2 geocode then how can I find through the geocode api?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) doesn't do that, it finds the geographic coordinates for an address.  The [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) or the [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/) will give you driving duration and distance between two (or more in the case of the distance matrix) locations.